# Is looping through a file and using `file.readline()` at the same time an "ok" practise?

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, parsing

I have written a piece of code in which within a `for` loop traversing the lines in a file i have some `file.readline()` statements. This seems very problematic to me although the script seems to be working fine. Just to demonstrate, assume you have the following in a file:

> ...bla bla
>
> Header signifying important stuff are coming
>
> important stuff line 1
>
> important stuff line 2
>
> important stuff line 3
>
> ...bla bla

This *header and important-stuff-lines block* appears multiple times so my script looks rougly like that:

```
with open(file, 'r') as fi:
    for line in fi:
        if header in line:
            a = fi.readline()
            b = fi.readline()
            c = fi.readline()
            continue
```

Both the `for line in fi` and the `fi.readline()` consume the same object (file) so after the `continue`, the next value for `line` would be 4 lines further down since 3 lines where consumed by the `readline()` calls.

As i said, the above works, but i am not a big supporter of the *"if it works it is not stupid"* movement.

On the other hand, an alternative approach would be this:

```
found_header = True
with open(file, 'r') as fi:
    for line in fi:
        if header in line:
            new_stuff_inc = []
            found_header = True
        elif found_header:
            new_stuff_inc.append(line)
        if len(new_stuff_inc) == 3:
            found_header = False
```

This seems safer, since the file *feeds one mouth* at a time (only `for line..` consumes it) but it looks unecessarily complicated..

**So, how should one go about doing something like that?**

Answer (score 3):

Mixing `for` and `readline()` is not very satisfactory, you're right, and BTW it does not work, so problem solved for the first snippet :) (tested with Python 2.7)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<module1>", line 3, in <module>
ValueError: Mixing iteration and read methods would lose data
```

Python just won't accept to iterate on a file line by line and a `readline` (a bit like when you iterate on a list and remove elements from it for instance, except that here it's protected)

And creating a state machine to be able to use `for` alone is cumbersome and bug-prone.

you could try another approach:

```
with open(file, 'r') as fi:
    while True:
        line = fi.readline()
        if not line:   # end of file
            break
        if header in line:
            a = fi.readline()
            b = fi.readline()
            c = fi.readline()
            continue
```

Comment: This is very interesting. In my machine no `ValueError` is raised.. I am using Python 3.5 btw. Since Python 3 is tagged, i would tone the *"it does not work"* down a notch. And the fact that it no longer raises an Error suggests that this might be a direction the python developers wanted to go towards..

Comment: Is it instead possible to call `next(fi)`?

Comment: `file.__next__` when used in a `for` loop was a slick fellow in Python 2 and used a hidden buffer to perform a bit better. This doesn't happen in Python 3. You could mix them together if you like without any side effects from what I know (they both act on the same underlying file iterator). It just looks weird.

Comment: @JimFasarakis-Hilliard couldn't you get a `StopIteration` exception in the loop when doing this? I agree you have to choose between for loop and while.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre no no, it returns an empty string on EOF.